# How to customize Google Calendar with CSS?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a `iframe` with `Google Calendar`:

```html
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%230c4da1&amp;src=example.com" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

**Doubt:**  I can customize `Google Calendar` using `CSS`? If not, I can customize otherwise?

I would like to change font size, color, etc.

Comment: see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe). Not possible normally. But the second answer there has a nasty hack that allows what you're wanting.

Comment: Is there another way to change `CSS`? API to do this?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus Not really AFAIK, most probably you 'll have to use a hack

Answer (score 8):

Google Calendar exposes its APIs. They are available here and these are the same APIs used to customize the layout for android Calendar app.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/

You can write whatever CSS/layout on top of these APIs

*Might not be related but there is an opensource repo that can help you in case you are only looking for google calendar events.*

Check this: 
http://sugi.github.io/jquery-gcal-flow/

Answer (score 6):

Found a bit of a work around! You can use the `filter` style  on the iframe itself

```
iframe{
   filter: invert(.9) saturate(0.5) hue-rotate(145deg);
}
```

So it goes from this:
[image]

to this:
[image]

Which I believe looks at least somewhat nicer

Comment: After a few hours of searching this seems to be a solution I'm looking for. Tapping into the gcal API is a bit overkill for me, and this looks 1 million times better with one line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [Styled Calendar](https://styledcalendar.com/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=forum-posts) which is a free service that allows you to style a Google Calendar embed with some UI options. It also allows custom CSS styles once the calendar is embedded.